# List index out of range, Does anyone know?

Tags: python, list, indexing, range, out

I am working with file tabel.txt  and  I'm having trouble with this. I want to display data from forth column but I am getting

```
error: list index out of range
```

Can anyone help me with this [image: Picture of this tabel.txt]

```
f = open("tabel.txt", 'r') 

for line in f:

a=line.split("\t")    
    print(a[3])
```

Comment: One of the lines doesn't have 3 columns and therefore raises the exception. I bet it's the last one with just a linefeed. TADA!

Comment: You are splitting by tab, so there aren't 3 columns maybe? third column would be a[2] anyways.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo it is the 4 column he is missing...

Comment: @OBP you're of course right :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [IndexError messages with python lists and split](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674609/indexerror-messages-with-python-lists-and-split)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
f = open("tabel.txt", 'r') 
for line in f:
    a=line.split("\t")  
    if len(a)>3:  
        print(a[3])    
    else:
        print a
```

This way you can see what is the problem in this line.
As said in one of the comments, 99% this is the last line.

Comment: @karlfel if this is what you were looking for, feel free to accept... :)

Answer (score 0):

As was noted already - most likely you are missing 4th column at some point. The good practice here would be using `try..except` if you are not sure about your data:

```
f = open("tabel.txt", 'r') 
i = 0
for line in f:

    a=line.split("\t")   
    try: 
        print(a[3]) 
    except IndexError:
        print("Empty field at line %s" % str(i))    
    i += 1
```

Comment: it is the 4th column he is missing